# Support strings with null charcters in C

Tags: c, string, null-terminated

C assumes strings are null terminated. To support strings with null characters in them, is there anything readily available in C?

Comment: There are no `char` strings in C with `'\0'` in them.  The `'\0'` character terminates the string.

Comment: By definition C strings are NUL terminated. No, there is no such thing in C. You need to write your own.

Comment: That is what I am asking. I am sure somebody has done it before (for example, python allow '\0' in a string). Where is a C library that supports `\0'?

Comment: Ah..so this is a library request....thanks for clarification. BTW, asking for a library is explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, strings in C don't contain null bytes because a null byte is what terminates a string.

If you're working with an array of characters that may contain null bytes, you'll need to process them yourself based on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

If array of chars contain null in middle it is not string. It should be array of bytes

`uint8_t bytes[5] = {0xFF, 0x00, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x01};` but dont use string functions like `strlen` on this.

`uint8_t` is equal to `signed char` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: *"If array of chars contain null in middle it is not string"* sure it is. It just terminates earlier.